# How do I put a shortcut to a folder inside a folder in XFCE's Thunar?

Tags: linux, shortcuts, xfce, thunar

This should be simple, but I can't find a way to do it. Inside one of my folders, let's call it Music, I want a link to a folder that's elsewhere on my drive, let's call it Albums, without having to copy and paste the actual folder. How do I do this in XFCE's Thunar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Thunar (Thunar for Kali here), right click on the file and select Send To and at that point you can create a shortcut or link. That is how it is working here.

Once you have the shortcut, you can drag it anywhere you please.

Comment: Where are you clicking after Send To? There's no obviously correct choices on my end.

Comment: When "Send to" has been selected, I use the option of "Desktop" . That puts the shortcut on the Desktop. Then I can drag the shortcut to whatever folder I want. That works very well.

Comment: Any luck with this issue. It all works and is straightforward.

Comment: Just tried it. It works only if I Send To the Desktop. There seems to be no other working choice. As a solution, this answer definitely works, but I can't shake the feeling that there should be a much simpler way.

Comment: Thanks. I use Kali for working here, so I tried several different ways , but the way above is the only way for Thunar.